# copyTo doesn't work on OpenCv4Android

Tags: opencv, mask, android

I would like to apply a mask with OpenCV4Android using the method copyTo(image, mask), but it is not working and the console doesn't show any errors.

[image: Image1 Mask]

[image: Image 2]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is too late but I had the same problem and it was because my "src" had 3 Channels and my "dst" had 4 Channels.

I just wrote this:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(src, auxiliar, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
auxiliar.copyTo(dst, mask);
```